# How to Create a single Trigger on multiple Database Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datatable, triggers

I have a database which contains some tables such as article, news, projects,...

I want to save a record to another table (Activity) when a record inserted into each table in database without activity

I don't want to create a trigger for each table.

How can I do it?

Comment: Triggers **are** table-based - you cannot create "database-wide" triggers ...

Comment: do you have an idea for do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use an intermediate layer, such as an ORM like Entity Framework, you could, in effect, have a "database wide" trigger, by overriding the OnSaveChanges event to add a log record anytime something is committed to the database.

My answer on [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599482/using-entity-framework-with-historical-data/6599556#6599556) does exactly that

Comment: Can I override OnSaveChanges Event?

Comment: Technically, you would want to override SaveChanges method of your implementation of ObjectContext. That is, if you are using entity framework.